# Sonar scm activity plugin?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I want to use scm activity plugin for tfs (with sonar and sonar runner) but it does not work, what is the problem,thanks

Error log;

```
13:49:13.257 INFO        org.sonar.INFO - Retrieve SCM info for C:\Program Files (x86)  \Jenkins\jobs\power\workspace\power\APICOM\Provider.cs
13:49:13.290 WARN         o.s.p.s.Blame - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\E-Power\workspace\power\APICOM\Provider.cs 
Reason: The tfs command failed.'tfpt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS is not supported by the Sonar SCM activity plugin, see that on the documentation: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Activity+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Team Foundation Power Tools, this package will also install the tfpt.exe executable.

TFPT 2010: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f
TFPT 2012: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35775